# Trouble Shuffling a MYSQL Result Set

Tags: php

Via database I am returning an array by:

```
print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

As expected everything looks good from there. But then I add the PHP "shuffle" function as so:

```
print_r(shuffle($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
```

The result is then "1". No shuffled array.

I am wanting to query a result set and them output them all in random order with a guarantee of no duplicates. Any help in regards will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[shuffle()](http://php.net/shuffle)** takes a reference to an array and return a boolean, you should do:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
shuffle($result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Totally missed that. Thank you for explaining!